# what can cause select() not to return?

Tags: c, sockets, posix

I'm writing a client and server that communicates through Unix Domain Sockets (for a task in POSIX Development class, just to learn the concept). What happens is that the client sends commands to the server, and the server parses them and responds with an answer. My problem is that the first query to the server isn't received by the clients, unlike the rest of them.

To be more clear, the first query to a given server instance isn't received by the client, if I close the client instance and open a new one, the first query will be received. It happens only for the first query to the **server** instance.

I'm attaching the relevant parts of the code from the client, the server works as a `select()` based server.

```
memset(&control, 0, sizeof(control));
control.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy(control.sun_path, CLIENT_PATH);

bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&control, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));

memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
server.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy(server.sun_path, SERVER_PATH);

while(1) {
FD_ZERO(&readfds);
FD_SET(sockfd, &readfds);
FD_SET(STDIN, &readfds);

    if (select(sockfd+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
        close(sockfd);
        perror("control: select");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &readfds)) {
        if ((nbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
            perror("recv");
        }
        buf[nbytes] = '\0';
        printf(">> %s", buf);
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(STDIN, &readfds)) {
        nbytes = read(STDIN, buf, sizeof buf);
        buf[nbytes] = '\0';
        if (sendto(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0,
                (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) < strlen(buf)) {
            perror("send");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a) `recvfrom` && `sendto` == `UDP` b) `UDP` && `the first query to the server isn't received by the clients, unlike the rest of them.` == `Not an error`. ... If you want reliable communication, use TCP or implement it yourself or use some lib or...

Comment: perror() is being called after close()  This is not a reliable order when trying to display a problem from select()  suggest reversing the order of the perror and close statements

Comment: suggest placing a timeout on the select() (the last parameter)  and checking for time expired.  When timeout occurs, loop back to send the string again.  Do remember to 'refresh' the timeout variable as some OSs (linux comes to mind) modify that variable

Comment: @deviantfan, These are UDS Datagrams. I don't understand b), could you please elaborate?

Comment: @user3629249, that's a very good practice indeed, but since I know that the server received the query and I know that it only occurs on the first query - I believe that sending the first query again would be an ugly fix that ignores the problem itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See man page: http://linux.die.net/man/2/select.
"If timeout is NULL (no timeout), select() can block indefinitely." You assigned it NULL (last parameter of select()), then select() will block until a socket is ready.

So what you need to do is to assign an struct timeval for time out. An 0 sec 0 usec timeout means return immediately, a positive one means return when there is socket ready for use (in your case for read) or timed out.

Comment: It's not clear that adding a timeout to select() will do anything to address his underlying problem, which is that the expected query data is not being received.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, I agree. I am checking that the data is being sent from the server and it is indeed sent.

Comment: I've set timeout to 0 and the problem stays the same. I start thinking it might be something with the fact that I `recvfrom()` and then use the details about the sender to `sendto()` the query answer.